# how to remove WCF service virtual directory in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Published a WCF service in VS, but in ISS there is no remove option when right clicking on the virtual directory. How can I remove the virtual directory under Default Web Site from IIS?

Comment: Make sure you are really talking about a virtual directory, as virtual directories of course can be removed, while physical directories cannot.

Comment: I just deleted the folder from the inetpub/wwwroot and it's gone now.

Comment: That's the only way to remove a physical folder.